# Ruby on Rails Neo4J Keymaker Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I'm creating a social network app with Neo4j and Rails, but I don't want to use Jruby..  I'm using devise, oauth, paperclip, koala, among other Gems - some of which might not work with Jruby)...

I've downloaded the Keymaker Gem, but I can't many examples of how to use this other than the github doc and http://www.neotechnology.com/2012/07/i-know-kung-fu-or-using-neo4j-on-rails-without-jruby/  ..

Can you point me to any more examples (Google didn't show much) that will show me how  to use this Gem - or any other Gem, to effectively and easily use Neo4j in my app?  Is there a better Gem to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely check out [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography), its pure Ruby and uses the HTTP wrapper API to access neo4j, its well documented and Max is (now) working at Neo Technology, the company behind Neo4j.

Neo4j is going to soon have a new API released (I found out from someone at Neo Technology a few weeks ago) that will make network API access even better, so neography's performance will even get better soon, although, if used properly, its already really good.

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of the gem.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you.. can I still use postgres/mysql alongside neo4j?  Can you tell me why it's better to use Neography instead of keymaker and vice versa?   I'd like to use neo4j as a server, not embedded.. Any downsides of not simply using jruby?  Thanks.

Comment: The obvious disadvantage is that going with jruby gives you direct access to the server: i.e. better performance.

Neography is not an ORM, so your active record won't be touched at all, meaning, whatever other database you are using, will still be used.

Keymaker doesn't seem to be maintained, last commit was done five months ago, which is not a great sign.

Comment: OK.. But what kind of performance difference?  10% decrease?  I mean I'd rather complete this prototype now, and worry about converting to Jruby later if necessary.. It's one thing to have to worry about performance with one million users, and another thing to launch a beta with a couple thousand/tens of thousands of users.  I'd rather launch sooner instead of rewriting - if performance degradation is barely noticeable to end users, I'll stick with Neography... .

Comment: The performance impact depends on the use case, if you are going to be making millions of atomic modifications that can be grouped in a batch then you will see "significant" performance impact, if that's not the case using the HTTP api should be safe, but again, it largely depends on the amount of operations and your particular use case. From what you say, I would assume that the performance impact of using the HTTP API makes it safe, and if need be you can refactor to use jruby and neo4j.rb.